# Get id of a table record

Tags: jquery

```
<?php foreach ($courses $course):?>
    <tr>

        <td><?php echo $course->bname;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $course->description;?></td>
        <td><div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Action</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Course/editCourse') . '/' . $course -> id; ?>">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class='deleteUser' href="<?php echo site_url('Course/deleteCourse') . '/' . $course -> id; ?>">Delete</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
        </td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

I am trying to delete a record from database using a jquery ajax call.
I am unable to get the relevant id of the clicked record to pass to Jquery.
Can some one explain how or any other alternatives. thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post your completed code and show us your attempts.

Comment: Are you using cakephp3 for the php part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var bname = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("td:eq(0)").text();
    //YOUR AJAX CODE AND PASS bname TO IT
});
```

Comment: Please consider using [`.closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) in your code, instead of `.parent()` x3, as it won't break if the developer decides to wrap the link in a div or span.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check your loop as you are missing an argument within your loop I am making some elements as in core you can convert accordingly to your MVC

```
<?php foreach ($courses as $course):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $course->bname;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $course->description;?></td>
    <td><div class="btn-group">
        <li><a href="#" onclick='delete(<?php echo $course->id; ?>)'>Delete</a></li>
  </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Now in your header you will run the following code to make this run and you will run a query in a separate file

```
function delete(userid) {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "includes/delete.php";
    var vars= "id="+userid;

    hr.open("POST", url, true);

    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 & hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }

    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Processing...";
}
```

Hope this will help you out